# SDK Manager: failed to install. How to fix it?

Tags: android

I am getting this error.

```
Stopping ADB server succeeded.
Failed to rename directory G:\Development_Softwares\Android\Development\SDK-Juno\android-sdk\platform-tools to G:\Development_Softwares\Android\Development\SDK-Juno\android-sdk\temp\PlatformToolPackage.old01.
[find_lock] Directory locked by eclipse.exe
```

Comment: Quit `eclipse.exe` from the Task Manager seems like a solution. Alternatively, how about using Android Studio?

Comment: Certainly migrate to AndroidStudio. Eclipse is not supported any more and even thou this seems like a simple thing, you should expect to start getting in to serious issues on it.